# Spark Transformers [Scala]: Knowing schema transformation result before feeding the full data

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-ml

Is there a method I could use If I want to know how a `Transformer` changes the schema; without providing the data? For example I have a large DataFrame but I don't want to use it with the transformer; I just want to know the occurring schema transformation without using the full data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Transfomer`'s are lazy (there is no `fit` stage) so even if you pass the data, there should be no significant delay.

However all `PipelineStages` (which include both `Transfromers` and `Estimators`) provide [`transformSchema`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.ml.PipelineStage@transformSchema(schema:org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType):org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType) method, which can be called directly, with `StructType` as an argument. For example if you have `StringIndexer` like this one

```
import org.apache.spark.ml.feature.StringIndexer

val indexer = new StringIndexer().setInputCol("foo").setOutputCol("foo_indexed")
```

and schema like this one

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._

val schema = StructType(Seq(StructField("foo", StringType)))
```

you can apply it as follows:

```
indexer.transformSchema(schema)
```

and get

```
org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType = StructType(StructField(foo,StringType,true), StructField(foo_indexed,DoubleType,false))
```